# Why is Linux not connecting to WLAN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, windows-8, connection

I have a tri-boot laptop, and two of the operating systems I have are Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 8. On Windows 8, I can access the WLAN, however whenever I restart the computer it defaults to having wireless turned off, and I have to turn it on so it can connect to the WLAN.

On Linux, I have the same problem but I do not know how to turn the wireless on, so I cannot connect to the internet while on Ubuntu.

If you need any additional info or want to ask a question, just throw me a comment.

Comment: If you continue to have issues, you should specify what hardware you have.

Comment: In Linux, what is the output of `iwconfig`?

Comment: @nerdwaller It says  
 eth0 - no wireless extensions
  lo - no wireless extensions

Comment: Try `lspci | grep -i net` to see your wireless card, research which drivers are required (and linux compatibility) and you can see which were requested in the OS by `lsmod`.  Sounds like it isn't even up (so either no driver or not enabled on boot), so I would probably try `ifconfig set wlan0 up` (if I remember right).  What does the Network Manager applet say when you open it?

Comment: @nerdwaller It was working a few days ago, just about 30 hours before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [rfkill](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/rfkill) to re-enable your wireless radio.

For example:

```
rfkill list
```

to see your wireless devices, and

```
rfkill unblock 0
```

to re-enable the device at index 0.

Note that if a device is "hard blocked" then you cannot re-enable it with rfkill. You have to flip the hardware switch, and possibly reboot the computer, to re-enable the device.

Comment: Hold on, I have a problem. It is still saying:
Offline: You have been disconnected
I have unblocked it and it is no longer soft blocked.
If you could help, much appreciated.